# Angular maps: Unable to get gMarker from markersScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm getting `Unable to get gMarker from markersScope!` (in angular maps: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/src/coffee/directives/api/models/parent/windows-parent-model.coffee#L146) when trying to add infoWindows. The windows do display, but behave erratically when updated.

Each time the user clicks on a movie the infoWindows should update with information about that movie at that cinema marker. It sometimes works, sometimes the infoWindows disappear and sometimes the markers disappear as well. The only error I get is the one above.

Controller and view code:

```
var createCinemaMarkers = function(cinemas) {
  $scope.cinemaMarkers = [];
  $scope.cinemaWindows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cinemas.length; i++) {

    getMoviesForCinema(cinemas[i].venue_id);

    var map_coords = {
      id: cinemas[i].venue_id,
      title: cinemas[i].title,
      options: {
        title: cinemas[i].title,
        random: 'blah blah blah'
      },
      clickable: true,
      latitude: cinemas[i].coords.lat,
      longitude: cinemas[i].coords.lng,
      icon: 'images/cinema_icons/cinema.png'
    }

    if (!cinemas[i].movieTitle) {
      cinemas[i].movieTitle = '';
    }

    var parameters = {
        movieTitle: cinemas[i].movieTitle,
        movieTimes: cinemas[i].movieTimes,
        stuff: 'from props'
    }

    var infoWindow = {
      id: cinemas[i].venue_id,
      coords: {
        latitude: cinemas[i].coords.lat,
        longitude: cinemas[i].coords.lng
      },
      options: {
        title: "I AM TITLE"
      },
      show: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/info-window.html',
      templateParameter: parameters,
      isIconVisibleOnClick: true,
      closeClick: 'none'
    }

  $scope.cinemaWindows.push(infoWindow);      
  $scope.cinemaMarkers.push(map_coords);
  };
};

    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" events="mapEvents">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="cinemaMarkers" events="events" options="'options'" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" fit="'true'"  popover-placement="top" popover="On the Top!">
        <ui-gmap-windows models="cinemaWindows" templateUrl="'templateUrl'" templateParameter="'templateParameter'" options="'options'">
        </ui-gmap-windows>
    </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where in the directive coords="'self'" but markers were set to coords: {latitude:xxxx,longitude:xxxxx}

Because your ui-gmap-markers is set to coords="'self'" so try remove **coords** in infoWindow:

```
var infoWindow = {
      id: cinemas[i].venue_id,
      latitude: cinemas[i].coords.lat,
      longitude: cinemas[i].coords.lng,
      options: {
        title: "I AM TITLE"
      },
      show: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/info-window.html',
      templateParameter: parameters,
      isIconVisibleOnClick: true,
      closeClick: 'none'
    }
```